# create a folder name variable dos command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i want to create a batch file

```
@echo off
set /p name="Type folder name(s):
md %name%
cd p:\%name%
```

all lines work, but i cannot change the directiory to `cd p:\%name%` when i run the script
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `cd /d` to change to a directory on another drive:

```
cd /d p:\%name%
```